# symfony 6 json_login: got 401 error but authenticated after refresh

Tags: json, ajax, symfony, authentication

I have followed the doc about json_login on symfony 6.
I got a 401 "missing credentials" and user is null after submit. But user is authenticated when refreshing the page.

Any idea would be appreciated.
Thanks.

security.yaml

```
providers:
    # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
    app_user_provider:
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\User
            property: username
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    main:
        lazy: true
        provider: app_user_provider
        
        json_login:
            check_path: app_login
            username_path: username
```

login controller

```
class LoginController extends AbstractController{
#[Route('/login', name: 'app_login', methods: ['POST'])]
public function login(#[CurrentUser] ?User $user): Response
{

    dump($user);
    if ($user===null){
        return $this->json([
            'message' => "missing credentials",
        ], Response::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);
    }


    return $this->json([
        'user' => $user->getUserIdentifier(),
    ]);
}
```

ajax request

```
const loginForm = document.getElementById('login_form');
        loginForm.addEventListener('submit',(e)=>{
            e.preventDefault();
            let username= document.getElementById('inputUsername').value;
            let password= document.getElementById('inputPIN').value;
            console.log(username,password)
            fetch('https://127.0.0.1:8000/login', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({username: username, password: password})
            })
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(result => console.log(result))
                .catch(error => {
                    if (error.response.data) {
                        this.error = error.response.data.error;
                    }else{
                        this.error = "unknown error";
                    }
                });
        })
```

Comment: This post can help you : [link](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/api-platform-security/json-login)

Comment: Also make sure you enter the password correctly when you register and manually (when you edit passwords directly in the database)

Comment: Thank you for the recommandation. I have already followed this post actually and it didn't help since this one is using api-platform in the next/previous lecture. He actually got a 200 response when login is correct, while i got a 401. It might be that the password should be hashed but I believe that it's not the issue since it authenticate after refreshing the page. BTW, the post that you mentioned also use vue.js and axios.  So I am a bit lost with it.

Comment: What is certain is that there is a problem between the front and the back. The connection has not gone properly to the back.

Comment: password_path configuration is missing.